# How do I prove that half of length n is $\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$

Tags: fractions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Lets assume there are n objects, ordered in a list.

How do I prove that the first half (including the middle element) of length n is $\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$?

And how do I prove that the last half (not including the middle element) of length n is $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$?

Thanks

Comment: what?! This question doesn't make sense to me.. why would the first half be greater than the other half?

Comment: If $n$ is even, then there are $\frac{n}{2}$ objects in the first and second half. If $n$ is odd then you can't spit the 'list' in two halves with the same number of objects. So if you want to define the notion of 'first-half' and 'second-half' one must have an extra object, but which is entirely arbitrary at the moment.

Comment: hint think about odd n and integer lengths for the half.

Comment: Its for a binary search, I think it chooses the higher value to divide it into 2 parts.

Comment: In the binary search algorithm, when there are $2k+1$ elements in the range you split it into blocks of size $k$ and $k+1$. If doesn't matter which block you choose for the middle element.

Comment: This really just uses the definition of the floor and ceiling.